# Search android sqlite database, return results to another activity as listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-intent, android-arrayadapter

I'm new to Android programming and learning about Sqlite. I am working on a project where a user can search for a car brand name(e.g. ferrari) in the populated database and the results will show on another activity as a listview of all model of the cars with same brand in the database. I've been looking for different methods(ArrayAdapter, Cursor, Intent) but I am not sure I am on the right track. I have four activities in total:
 **CarDbAdapter.java**(SqliteDatabase) includes this method to find the car brand

```
public ArrayList<Car> findCar(String Car) {
String car = new String();
ArrayList<Car> car= new ArrayList<Car>();
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand=?", new           
String[]{car});
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
Car c = new Car
(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("model")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("reviews")));
            car.add(c);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return car;
}
```

**RequestCar.java** this is where users can request car info from database through edittext and button

```
public class RequestCar extends AppCompatActivity {
CarDbAdapter db;
Button search;
EditText brand, model, reviews;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_car);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    db = new CarDbAdapter(this);

    search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchButton);
    brand= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.brand);
    model= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.model);
    reviews = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reviews);


    searchCar();

}
// This is where it goes wrong. Do I need to initialise another arraylist?As I've already done it on CarDbAdapter.java

public void searchCar() {
    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Car> carIntent= db.searchCar(brand.getText().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(RequestCar.this, CarList.class);
            intent.putStringArrayListExtra("car", carIntent);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

**CarList.java** where I call the intent from main activity and view the results as a list.

```
 public class CarList extends AppCompatActivity {
CarDbAdapter db;
ListView carList;
String uriString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_car_list);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    db = new CarDbAdapter(this);


    carList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.carList);

    handleIntent();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

public void handleIntent(){
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    uriString = intent.getStringExtra("car");

    }
}
// This is what I've done so far because I'm getting confused with loads of tutorials and I'm not sure which one to follow. I've read about tutorials suggesting ArrayAdapter for creating the list but first I need to know how to get the Intent from mainactivity then maybe I can learn more about the ArrayAdapter.
```

**Car.java**

```
public class Car{

int id = 0;
String brand = null;
String model = null;
String reviews = null;

public Car(int id, String brand, String model, String reviews) {
    this.id = id;
    this.brand= brand;
    this.model = model;
    this.reviews = reviews;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBrand() {

    return brand;
}

public void setBrand(String brand) {

    this.brand= brand;
}

public String getModel() {

    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {

    this.model= model;
}

public String getReviews() {
    return reviews;
}

public void setReviews(String reviews) {
    this.reviews= reviews;
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated. If anyone could guide me with already existing tutorials which I can follow would be fantastic. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **CarDbAdapter.java**, these are the first three lines:

```
public ArrayList<Car> findCar(String Car) {
String car = new String();
ArrayList<Car> car= new ArrayList<Car>();
```

You are creating a method which returns an ArrayList of Car (class) type. then you pass a String with name "Car" (which is the same of your Car class). 
Inside the method, you create an empty string with name "car", and then you create an ArrayList of type Car (class), with the same name "car" (which overwrites your previously created String "car".

This is not confusing only us, but also your compiler. Try renaming the variables and running your application again.

This is a suggestion of how I would rewrite your **findCar** method:

```
public ArrayList<Car> findCar(String brand_text) {
ArrayList<Car> cars= new ArrayList<Car>();
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cars WHERE brand=?", new           
String[]{brand_text});
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    Car c = new Car (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")),cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("brand")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("model")),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("reviews")));
    cars.add(c);
    cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
cursor.close();
return cars;
```

}

This way, you use "brand_text" as the string value of your brand (e.g., "ferrari"), and return an ArrayList cars, of class type Car.

As to your doubt, Intents are used (also) to pass parameters to other activities, Cursors are used (also) to return rows from your database, and ArrayAdapters are used to populate your ListViews. It is not a matter of **which** you should be using. You actually will have to use all of them, if you plan to use the application as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: That actually helped me a lot. Thank you!!